# Angular 6 - get value from a datetimepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Im using this [datetimepicker](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in Angular, when the datetime is selected, how can I get that value and show it in the p element below?

```
<dl-date-time-picker minuteStep="15" ></dl-date-time-picker>
<p class="text-secondary"></p>
```

Comment: <dl-date-time-picker minuteStep="15" (change)="onChange($event) ></dl-date-time-picker> . build a function onChange and use the event properties

Comment: Use [(ngModel)]

Comment: don't work [(ngModel)]? I'm too lazy to check the code or download, but the code implement ControlValueAntecesor, so, I supouse thid datetimepicker can be used in a ReactiveForm and in template from and using [(ngModel)]="variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try [(change)](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/components/DlDateTimePickerComponent.html) event:

HTML

```
<dl-date-time-picker minuteStep="15" (change)="dateChanged($event)"></dl-date-time-picker>
<p class="text-secondary">{{somethingChanged | json}}</p>
```

TS

```
{
  somethingChanged: any; // type????

  ....

  dateChanged(val: any) {
    console.log('Date changed', val);
    this.somethingChanged = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: almost there I think, the selected value is showing as [object Object]

Comment: LOL, modified answer to display as JSON however it is up to you to use proper type and use whatever pieces of the object returned you need.

Comment: great stuff, thanks.  Im new to Angular and was just unsure what to pass in to any function.

Comment: Good luck & happy coding.

Comment: @PeS, I'am almost sure that you can use [(ngModel)]="variable" (in html you can write {{variable|json}} and check the values

Comment: @Eliseo yes, you most probably can, of course. Not a big fan of `[(anything)]` though, unlike you :)